# How to map a process with three states to two states?

Tags: state, automata

Let's say I have a device running in three states High, Medium, and Low in a sequence, like the following.

LLLLLLMMMHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHMMMLLLLLLL

Now, I want to map these three states to a sequence of two states High and Low, so that I can control the input power.

LLLLLLHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHLLLLLLLL

How do I do that? Are there any concepts in math or computer science that might help me out with this problem? I thought of coming up with a logic like if the input states are Medium or High then the output is High else if input state is Low output state is low. Is there any other better way to map these states?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It isn't clear why you think you need any kind of advanced mathematics or computer science here. Use power states that make your device work. We have no idea what they are.

Comment: I thought I could analyze the sequence to infer something from it.

Comment: @Dhineshkumar I think the method i suggested would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Another method which I can suggest is transition of [signal edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_edge) to appropriate state.

> A rising edge is the transition from low to high. [...] A falling edge is the high to low transition.

So if you want to implement this in your case, You can convert all medium in between low to high into high and all medium that comes in between high to low to low.

I think this would be more  efficient.